# Z3: check that variable is a prime number

Tags: z3

Is there a way to constrain a variable `a0` to be prime? My best attempt is to use:

```
(assert (or (= a0 2) (= a0 3) (= a0 5) (= a0 7)...(= a0 541)))
```

This forces me to hardcode the list of primes (in this case the first 100) and significantly reduce the possible answer space. I saw another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315086/z3-prime-numbers) but this seems computationally expensive. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. There's no easy primality check.